# Написание обработчиков "сложных текстов"

Tags: c#

Приветcтвую вас, ув. сообщество!

Недавно передо мной появилась задача реализовать некоторый парсер (хотя этот термин не очень подходит) текстовой информации, которая может содержать не только разметку (например, здесь используется [Markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/markdown_help/)), но и определённые команды.

С разметкой всё понятно, для кажного блока разметки пишем что-то такое (не помню уже, где нашёл этот код, но он поразительно хорошо работает):

```
new RegexFormatter(@"\[url=((.|\n)*?)(?:\s*)\]((.|\n)*?)\[/url(?:\s*)\]", 
                    "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>"));
```

Потом в цикле перебираем все паттерны для всего текста и выполняем преобразование (если подскажите более оптимальный способ, тоже буду благодарен).

Но что делать, если в тексте могут быть команды, которые должны выполнять взаимодействие с БД, или любую другую логику? Допустим, я пишу самописную сайтовую [консоль](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/). Как находить их в тексте, как определять, какая команда в тексте выполняет какую команду на языке программрования?

Я, конечно, могу написать в лоб какой-нить велосипед, но хотелось бы понять, как делать это правильно. Может кто подскажет, или хотя бы литературу подкинет?

Зарание огромное спасибо!

**UDP:** немного уточнил вопрос.

Comment: А регэксп тут причем? Декорация? Парсер - это конечный автомат, про них и надо читать.

Comment: Насчет команд:  
Проще всего создать метатэг вроде  

    [eval command]
Не знаю насколько хороша реализация [c# eval][1], попробуйте посмотреть ее.  
В крайнем случае всегда можете сами написать что-нибудь с помощью [Reflection][2].  
То есть Вам не нужно будет парсить отдельно взятые команды и переводить ее в код- можно будет выполнить любую команду из шаблона.

[1]:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13335/C-Eval-Function
[2]:http://nnm.ru/blogs/Catone/reflection_v_net_s_primerami_na_c/

Comment: метатэг - хорошая идея, спасибо, а eval - в любом своём проявлении evil

Comment: eval - ток что посмотрел вроде бы тот же словарь команд, только в собран в удобный вид

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Формальная_грамматика

Comment: @Gorets он не может быть набором команд. Скорее всего он базируется на Reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, что же это за "сложный текст", китайский что-ли? откуда там может быть ссылки, выборки и тд?

1. если это штмл страничка - я бы брал готовую либу, их много есть, или даже есть готовые фреймы в языке, которые читают разметку.
2. если эта программа - какой-то специальный транслятор, то, если делать по простому:

   1. написал бы словарь команд, парсер текст по слову и сравнивал со словарем,
      если неделать немного сложнее и возможно правильнее, то
   2. надо бы все делать конечным автоматом и тогда уже с каждого состояния делать нужный переход 
      Ну и конечно, остается еще вариант с регулярками, но я как всегда против него =)

Comment: > Непонятно

в вашем ответе есть же нумерованные списки, так же там могли быть и ссылки, и прочее, а мне необходимо предусмотреть возможность, что там будут ещё и команды, которые будут выполнятся на сервере

поиск совпадений в словаре - самый очевидный вариант, а нём я думал в первую очередь