# Как определить что ввел пользователь?

Tags: c#

Всем привет, многие из вас знают что такое GM(Game Master) команды, это к примеру

```
/kick **ИМЯ ИГРОКА**
```

Так, так мне интересно такое, у меня есть textBox1 и когда в него пользователь вводит

```
/select_пробел_**ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ**
```

тогда то что **ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ** заносилось в какую-нибудь переменную, и дальше уже можно было работать с получиченными данными. Извините за кривизну объяснения, но я просто с этим вообще впервые столкнулся, и не знаю даже как сформулировать мысль, но есть одно очень хорошое подобие Командная строка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если строка имеет вид `/select UserName` и больше ничего, то как-то так:

```
var str = textBox.Text.Split(' ');
if(str[0] == "/select")
    UserName = str[1];
```

если может содержать что-то другое, то с такой проблемой и я сталкивался - [Написание обработчиков "сложных текстов"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/95870/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Спасибо всё работает отлично.